# why i can not open this url on scrapy shell?

Tags: shell, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

when i ran

> scrapy shell https://partsouq.com/en/catalog/genuine/unit?c=Toyota&ssd=%24HQwdcgcAAwFNa3Y_IS9WZm1SC1BrWUo%24&vid=4463&cid=&uid=2535&q=

I get nothing. the curser blinks like in the screenshot

how to scrap this page?[image]

Answer (score 1):

scrapy shell "https://partsouq.com/en/catalog/genuine/unit?c=Toyota&ssd=%24HQwdcgcAAwFNa3Y_IS9WZm1SC1BrWUo%24&vid=4463&cid=&uid=2535&q="

solved the problem

Comment: There's a note on using quotes [in the tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data).